# How to delete Amazon DynamoDB items using LocalSeondaryIndex?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

I defined my dynamoDB as below in cloudformation script:

```
TodosDynamoDBTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: userId
        AttributeType: S           
      - AttributeName: createdAt
        AttributeType: S                                     
      - AttributeName: todoId
        AttributeType: S                                               
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: userId
        KeyType: HASH   
      - AttributeName: createdAt
        KeyType: RANGE                                   
    BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
    TableName: ${self:provider.environment.TODOS_TABLE}
    LocalSecondaryIndexes:
      - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.TODOID_INDEX}
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH        
          - AttributeName: todoId
            KeyType: RANGE               
        Projection:
          ProjectionType: ALL # What attributes will be copied to an index
```

Now I want to look up the item based on the userId and todoId. So i used the typescript code below:

```
  const key = {
    userId: userId,
    todoId: todoId
  }

  await docClient.delete({
      TableName: todosTable,
      Key: key
  }).promise();
```

But this gives me an error from CloudWatch

```
2020-06-19T18:03:17.349Z    00a89359-428f-4a7d-b63c-500e7d062c1b    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "ValidationException",
    "errorMessage": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
    "code": "ValidationException",
    "message": "The provided key element does not match the schema",
    "time": "2020-06-19T18:03:17.347Z",
    "requestId": "7EJTPMFQKEUTQAKNI1UVQ0FRF7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
    "statusCode": 400,
    "retryable": false,
    "retryDelay": 6.9291082443874386,
    "stack": [
        "ValidationException: The provided key element does not match the schema",
        "    at constructor.httpResponse (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:47:1)",
        "    at constructor.shift [as callListeners] (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:100:1)",
        "    at constructor.doneCallback [as emit] (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:75:1)",
        "    at constructor.call [as emitEvent] (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:1)",
        "    at constructor.emit (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:1)",
        "    at r.call [as runTo] (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:1)",
        "    at runTo (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:1)",
        "    at constructor.done (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:1)",
        "    at constructor.call (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:1)",
        "    at constructor.Error [as callListeners] (/var/task/src/lambda/http/webpack:/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:108:1)"
    ]
}
```

What is the proper syntax to delete based on userId and/or todoId?

UPDATE:
docClient is created from standard boilerplate aws XRay and DynamoDB

```
const XAWS = AWSXRay.captureAWS(AWS)
const docClient = new XAWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()
```

I am also able to query using

```
  const result = await docClient.query({
    TableName: todosTable,
    IndexName: todoIdIndex,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'userId = :userId and todoId = :todoId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':userId': userId,
      ':todoId': todoId
    }
  }).promise()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what it is with document client, but this should be what you need. Basically query first, then delete. This is because your table is indexed with `userId` and `createdAt`, so you need to figure those out before you can delete the entry

```
const result = await docClient.query({
    TableName: todosTable,
    IndexName: todoIdIndex,
    KeyConditionExpression: 'userId = :userId and todoId = :todoId',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':userId': userId,
      ':todoId': todoId
    },
    ProjectionExpression: 'userId, createdAt'
  }).promise()

if (result.$response.data && result.$response.data.Items) {
    const key = {
        userId: result.$response.data.Items[0]['userId'],
        createdAt: result.$response.data.Items[0]['createdAt']
    }
    await docClient.delete({
        TableName: todosTable,
        Key: key
    }).promise()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added docClient expalantion in the update section in the post. Where is the db coming from in your code?

Comment: I also added how I can query the item....Could you suggest what I should do? I am trying to delete using todoId and userId, not createdAt...

Comment: since your table is indexed with userId and createdAt, but your LSI is indexed with userId and todoId, you need to query with userId and todoId first, and that should return userId and createdAt. Then you can user createdAt to delete the item.

Comment: i updated my answer for my best guess at the docclient implementation

Comment: Thank you. So there is no way to delete based on userId and todoId? I see you use userId and createdAt.